# MediaWiki - restrict access to namespace

Tags: linux, mediawiki, wiki, lockdown

Within **MediaWiki 1.31.8**, I need to restrict access to pages in a namespace so only members of a group would be able to use/view it.

The wiki has over 500 pages that begin with "MARKETING:"

I have created a namespace by adding this to LocalSettings.php:

```
"$wgExtraNamespaces =
       array (104 => "MARKETING",
             105 => "MARKETING_Talk");
```

I then installed Lockdown and added this line to LocalSettings.php:

```
$wgNamespacePermissionLockdown[MARKETING]['*'] = ['marketing'];
(I've seen some users have "marketing" as their group in the wiki "ListUsers" webpage)
```

I then went to test it in incognito (to avoid cookies error) with a dummy user that has no groups with the expectation that he won't have any privileges but it just didn't work. I've noticed that I can enter gibberish into the code above and it doesn't change anything or even throw logs. Would really appreciate the help, thanks ahead.

**EDIT: SOLVED. Turns out since the marketing namespace is set with an array, I have had to use the syntax for an array:**

```
$wgNamespacePermissionLockdown = array_fill( 104, 105, [  '*' => [ 'marketinhRW'  ] ] );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confusing namespace names, IDs and constants. `104` is the namespace ID, `MARKETING` is the namespace name. Almost everything takes a namespace ID (not name) as key, `$wgNamespacePermissionLockdown` included.

Conventionally, you'd define a human-readable constant for the namespace ID, by putting `define( 'NS_MARKETING', 104 )` somewhere in your configuration, and then write `$wgNamespacePermissionLockdown[NS_MARKETING]['*'] = ['marketing'];` which will index by ID. If you instead write `$wgNamespacePermissionLockdown[MARKETING]`, since there is no `MARKETING` constant, PHP will assume you meant to write `'MARKETING'`, and treat it as a string, so there will be no permissions defined for the namespace ID.